# NVCC Compiler Crashes after hours of compilation

Tags: compilation, cuda, crash, gpu, nvcc

For some reason, NVCC is crashing when trying to compile a GPU program with very long double-precision arithmetic expressions, of the form

```
// given double precision arrays A[ ], F[ ], 
__global__ myKernel(double *A, double *F, long n){
      //.......thread ids
      A[t+1] = A[t]*F[t+1] + ...... (order of million of terms).... + A[t-1]*F[t]
}
```

The same code does get compiled successfully with GCC (around 30 minutes compiling) and even executes correctly.

The crash occurs after +20hrs of compilation time, with the following error:

```
nvcc error   : 'cicc' died due to signal 11 (Invalid memory reference)
nvcc error   : 'cicc' core dumped
make: *** [Makefile:28: obj/EquationAlfa.cu.o] Error 139
```

As a side note, if we change the GPU program to 32-bit float, then it does compile correctly, although still taking hours to compile.
The compilation line is this:

```
nvcc -std=c++14  -c -o obj/EquationAlfa.cu.o src/EquationAlfa.cu
```

NVCC version:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
 Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
 Built on Mon_Nov_30_19:08:53_PST_2020
 Cuda compilation tools, release 11.2, V11.2.67
 Build cuda_11.2.r11.2/compiler.29373293_0
```

During compilation, the RAM usage does not exceed 8~10GB, and the computer has 128GB of RAM.
Any help or directions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's evidently a compiler bug.  I suspect its unlikely you'll find any meaningful help here.  My suggestion would be to file a bug at developer.nvidia.com using the instructions [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-report-a-bug/67911).  Be advised that you will likely be asked for a description of how to reproduce the issue, which may involve providing (a complete) code.

Comment: @RobertCrovella many thanks, we will do that, and include a program to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Millions of terms? (unless you have some weird machine that can do all of those parallelly and the compiler don't know that, or can't turn it into a for loop for some reason) perhaps you can somehow rewrite that to use a loop, and it will make both compilation faster and the run time can stay similar.

Comment: @user202729 Hi, the code is generated from the FDTD statement of some theoretical physics coupled PDEs. It already comes simplified from previous symbolic math. Indeed, we agree that if it could be written as loops, it would not reach the compiler bug. We are checking if at least part of the expression could follow a loop pattern.

Comment: That's only a workaround. Alternatively if that's still not possible, a possible workaround is to separate it into multiple assignment expressions (`auto subexpression1 = ...; autosubexpression2 = ...; etc.`)

Comment: Indeed, we considered that one if the compiler error was inevitable. Many thanks